# How to replace html content inside DIV tag with regular expressions in multiple files with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, sublimetext3

I have a folder with html files. Every file contains that code:

```
<div class="header-info-box">
 This HTML content is different in all files.
</div>
```

How to find and replace whole div content in all files which contains that div tag with specific class name?

Answer (score 0):

Play around in some online regex testers and see if you can do it.
Some of them even explains the steps its taking and provides cheatsheets.

Comment: https://regexr.com/43s07 I did it, but how to use it in Sublime or VSCode?

Comment: Dont know about Sublime, but in VSCode you can replace(CTRL+F) using regex, and reference your groups in the replace string with $1 and $2